# Date Detection on iOS: How to go about detecting and processing dates on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, date, uitextview, nsdatadetector

First off, the platform I'm working on: **Swift 3 + iOS 10.3**.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- A user attempts to type in some text in a text view, which includes a time in some UITextView. For example: ***"Meeting at 10pm today"***.
- Now that I have the text, I want to glean the date from the event, which is ***"10pm today"***.
- I want to convert this information into a `Date()` object.

What I know and have tried so far:

- **NSDataDetectors:** They are pretty useful for extracting this information from strings, but as you can see here, the user can input dates in a variety of formats, making it impossible for me cover all kinds of date formats for the `NSDateFormatter()`.
- **UITextViews:** They have data detection built-in, but this is primarily for non-editable text and is optimal for user-interaction purposes directly in the UI. I just need to extract this information.

What does it already?
**macOS.** If you have used the **Reminders** or **Calendar** on macOS, inputting reminders/events is easy: In calendar, adding an event saying **"Meeting at 10pm"** creates an event called **Meeting** scheduled at **10pm** and does not simply convert the whole text and create an event called **"Meeting at 10pm"**.

So I am wondering as to how I can harness the above capability on iOS, which seems built-in on macOS? There seem to be no posts or tutorials on this specific capability (at least I could not find any). If there is no API for this, I would appreciate it if anyone could suggest an alternative to process dates from text such that I am able to accomplish the above.

Comment: I decided to develop a framework wrapper around NSDataDetector: https://github.com/mayankk2308/mkdatadetector-swift